# APIGateway does not perform request validation when called using POSTMan

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Just learning my way through AWS - I have an APIGateway REST API setup with Lambda proxy integration. The API has a model defined, and request validation setup on the body using this model.

Say the model is

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "propertyA": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "propertyB": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "propertyC": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "propertyD": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "required": ["propertyA", "propertyB", "propertyC", "propertyD"]
}
```

Now, if I test the API via APIGateway console, and purposely give an invalid input (omitting a required property `propertyD`):

```
{
    "propertyA": "valueA",
    "propertyB": "valueB",
    "propertyC": "valueC"
}
```

the request fails with the error(400): `Sun Jul 11 13:07:07 UTC 2021 : Request body does not match model schema for content type application/json: [object has missing required properties (["propertyD"])]`

But when I invoke the same API(and stage) with the same invalid input from Postman, the validation seems to be not happening, and request is proxied to Lambda, which even returns a 200 OK as long as I comment out the parts of code that depend on `propertyD`.

What's the difference here? Should I be passing in any request header from the client side? I couldn't find anything from the AWS documentations

Answer (score 8):

Answering my question-

Issue was with the headers used in the request - Postman defaulted the JSON as a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`, I had to switch to JSON using the dropdown in Body tab to make PostMan set the Content-Type to application/json

<s>Following this post seems to have fixed the problem: https://itnext.io/how-to-validate-http-requests-before-they-reach-lambda-2fff68bfe93b, although it doesn't explain how</s>

Apparently the magic lies with the config adding `Content-Type` Header under `HTTP Request Headers` section, even though the header is set correctly as `application/json` in PostMan.